# Change a website's directory names per installation

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way that I can have different directory names per installation of a website? As in I would need to rename the directories at build time or some similar solution. I am currently using MSBuild with CruiseControl.NET.

An example would be I have a module in my website called Bug Tracking which is then in http://mysite.com/BugTracking/.

One installation wants to leave it as BugTracking and another would like to call it "Issue Tracking" for whatever reason and have it in http://theirsite.com/IssueTracking/.

Comment: What Framework are you targeting? 2.0, 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Re-writer rules

You could set up a re-writer rules so you could leave the directory name the same, and just add a re-writer rule for the clients that want it call something different?

[IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)

also look at [Scott's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Doesn't solve the problem, kind of hides it I know.  but its easy :)

or

### ASP.NET Routing:

Also worth looking at would be ASP.NET Routing,

[Using ASP.NET Routing Without ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131035/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx) 
or
[Using Routing With WebForms](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx)

Comment: I was using 2.0 but there was no reason I couldn't upgrade to 3.5. This solution looks perfect for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have use ReWritter rules for a long time.. but if i had to start this i would love to try out routing.. i think it would be fun :)

Good Luck